# Variable initial condn NDSolve with earlier version

Tags: differential-equations, version-8

In an earlier version 8 (ParametricNDSolve not available) I tried to integrate with different initial values $ (yi= 0.1, 0.4,0.8); (zi^2+yi^2=1) $ radially on unit semi circle to sketch tractrices  but not successful. Is there a workaround?

$$ \sin \phi = y/a,\, \tan \phi= \frac{dy}{dz} $$

[image: IC NDSolve problem]

```
a = 1; zmax = 1; ri = 0.8; zi = -Sqrt[a^2 - ri^2]; ar = 0.5;
{zi, ri}
NDSolve[{R'[z]/(R[z] (1 + R'[z]^2)^0.5) == 1/a, R[0] == ri}, 
  R, {z, zi, zmax}];
r[t_] = R[t] /. First[%];
ps8 = Plot[{r[z], 0}, {z, zi, zmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   AspectRatio -> ar, GridLines -> Automatic];
semicirc = 
ParametricPlot[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    GridLines -> Automatic];
Show[{semicirc, ps1, ps4, ps8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your version?

Comment: Mathematica Version 8

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to portray both solutions. Using `DSolve`, we construct two functions (for each branch of the solution)

```
trac1[ri_, x_] := 
 Block[{r = ri, a = 1, z = x}, 
  s = DSolve[{R'[z]/(R[z] (1 + R'[z]^2)^(1/2)) == 1/a, R[0] == ri}, 
    R[z], z]; R1 = R[z] /. s[[1]]; R1]

p1 = Plot[
  Evaluate[Table[trac1[ri, x], {ri, {.2, .4, 0.8}}]], {x, -1, 1}];

trac2[ri_, x_] := 
 Block[{r = ri, a = 1, z = x}, 
  s = DSolve[{R'[z]/(R[z] (1 + R'[z]^2)^(1/2)) == 1/a, R[0] == ri}, 
    R[z], z]; R2 = R[z] /. s[[2]]; R2]

p2 = Plot[
  Evaluate[Table[trac2[ri, x], {ri, {.2, .4, 0.8}}]], {x, -1, 1}];



With[{a = 1}, 
  semicirc = 
   ParametricPlot[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]];

Show[{semicirc, p1, p2}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thanks for separation of the plots, now I know how we can better vary a single boundary condition parameter. The tractrix through $(0,0.8)$ however has positive curvature,  seems not alright to me.Will it change on later versions? I again plotted by repetitive computation as Shown at right..I am still trying to find under what conditions curves whose differential equations are given by constant $ \sin \phi /r, \cos \phi/r $ cease to be orthogonal.

Comment: @Narasimham You're right. We cannot solve this problem using `NDSolve[]`. Therefore, I changed the code. See update.

Comment: Fine. What still bothers me is ...a trace is found for orthogonal trajectory even outside unit semi-circle earlier to boundary start point .. it seems the computation re-visits  DE to somehow make it more comprehensive, a matter not bargained for a priori.!! Seems we are not in control of the DE..

Comment: @Narasimham Can you explain what you want to get?

Comment: For example tractix should not *pass through* boundary points $ ( .8,-.6  ),(  .4,-.9165 ),  ( .1,,.9950  ) $ but should actually *start* at these points. I want to know why it is not so in the simple ODE integration.

Comment: @Narasimham I do not understand what is the boundary point?

Comment: E.g., the point $ ( -0.8,0.6 ) $  is initial point in the initiial value problem.  Even though tractrix function is monotonous the locus moves on either side not just down.